# Cohomology of Deligne-Lusztig variety associated to Coxeter element

Tags: reductive-groups, weyl-group, deligne-lusztig-theory

Determining the individual ($l$-adic) cohomology groups of Deligne-Lusztig varieties has only been done for the general linear group and for some other very specific cases (as far as I know).
However, it seems to be the case that these $H^i_c(X(w))$ are known when $w$ is a Coxeter element in the Weyl group, for any reductive group $G$.
Does someone have a good reference for this?

I cannot find it in G. Lusztig's paper "Coxeter Orbits and Eigenspaces of Frobenius" and also not in other papers that I have been reading...
So until now this statement seems to be a bit of folklore...

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I think that in the Coxeter case a full description is given in Lusztig's paper "Coxeter Orbits and Eigenspaces of Frobenius" mentioned in the question. More precisely, the individual cohomology groups, with their decomposition into Frobenius eigenspaces, can be deduced from Theorem 6.1 + the table in Section 7.3 of this article. Moreover, each eigenspace is an irreducible unipotent $G(\mathbb{F}_q)$-module, appearing exactly once.